# Null safety Problem while getting current user data using FirebaseAuth class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am new in Flutter and trying to learn Firebase. In the given below code,I am trying to get data of currentUser that is logged in. But I get **_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)**. I tried to solve it but couldn't accomplished it. How can I solve it?

````
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!; 
    var useremail = "Error";
    if (user.email != null) {   //********Problem occurs here**********
      var useremail = user.email;
    }
    print("$user");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("HomeScreen"),
          ],
        )),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(useremail),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(); 
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                    ));
                  },
                  child: Text("Sign Out")),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the above block of code by this:

```
final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser; 
var useremail = "Error";
if (user?.email != null) {
  useremail = user!.email!;
}
```

The problem is that you gave an exclamation after FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser, that stated that the user can't be null.

Also, don't forget to check if user is null or not before signing him out.

To learn more about null safety, visit: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: I implemented your solution but I still get error in **useremail = user.email** line :(. Do you have any other solution pls?

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: The property 'email' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: The answer above is updated. Implement it and please let me know.

Comment: Yes it works,I don't get any error. user.email is null right now. Do you know why. The user is logged in

Comment: Can you explain what  double ! do in **user!.email!** as well pls

Comment: ! after any variable states that the current variable is not null forcefully (even though it might be null). In case the variable is not null, then the code works fine, but if the variable is null, then we get the error null check operator used on a null value.
It is a basic principle of null safety. You can check and learn more about it from  https://dart.dev/null-safety . 
If my answer worked for you, I suggest you to accept the answer. It'd be a great help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking that user.email != null , also verify that the user object is not null.